# Long String Used in Java

Tags: java, string, file

Let say I have to used a two paragraph string in my java program. What would be the best approach on this? Should the paragraph saved in a file and retrieved when used? Or there are better approach?

Comment: _used a two paragraph string in my java program_: How? Is it typed?(hardcoded) there?

Comment: We need some more details. What do you need to do with the text? Do you need to be able to search the text, or change things about the text, or change how it's displayed? These details are important to figure out how you need to represent this text.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If the paragraphs will never change, then it might make sense to embed them directly in the source code. This has the advantage that no extra files are needed to run your code.

If you expect that the paragraphs might change, it's probably better to put them in an external file because that allows somebody to modify the text without having to recompile the program. This could be beneficial if those who modify are not programmers.

Answer (score 1):

and just to add if u need concatenate these two paragraph strings together a better approach is to use the StringBuffer class and append them.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've seen a String with that kind of length on it would be in internationalized [property files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).  This keeps them separate from logic, and make editing the paragraph/necessary code simpler.

In short, yes, the better approach would be to store the String in its own separate file.  However, there shouldn't be any reason to have one *that* long - even with property files, it's better to break those out too.